# Can't see Dropbox folder within localhost

Tags: permission, apache, dropbox

I've setup Apache for web development on Yosemite. It's setup fine and I'm able to view folders within my documentroot using `http://localhost` as I'd expect to.

I now want to use my Projects folder within Dropbox using Apache so have moved my Dropbox folder within the documentroot. There are other directories within documentroot as well.

The problem is when using `http://localhost` to navigate around these directories, the Dropbox directory doesn't show in the browser. Nothing within it is accessible either. The directories sitting alonsgide are accessible as I'd expect. I think it's probably a permissions thing with the Dropbox directory.

I'm in the process of switching my dev environment from Windows (where this wouldn't have been a problem) to Mac so apologies if I'm missing anything. How do I make sure I can see and use this Dropbox directory when viewing its parent using `http://localhost`?

Comment: How do you try to access your Dropbox folder in the browser (screenshots or step-by-step instructions may help)? And why do you think your installation of Apache (which is a web server which has nothing to do with Safari or Dropbox) is related to the issue?

Comment: Apache isn't the cause, it's the context. I think the cause is permissions on the Dropbox directory. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Open Info window (Command+I) and check Shared Folder.

[image]